# how to watch the sub-znodes of znodes please?

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I use the Curator to program the Zookeeper.I want to watch the sub-znodes of zonde.My code looks like:

```java
CuratorFramework frameWork = CuratorFrameworkFactory.builder()
            .retryPolicy(new RetryNTimes(3, 1000))
            .connectString("127.0.0.1:2181").build();
frameWork.start();

CuratorWatcher watcher = new CuratorWatcher () {

            @Override
            public void process(WatchedEvent event) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("event :" + event);
            }
            
        };
frameWork.getChildren().usingWatcher(watcher).forPath("/aa"); 
frameWork.setData().forPath("/aa/dd", "asdfd".getBytes());
```

When the setdata for "/aa/dd" is called, I want the watcher is triggered.But failed, does anyone have idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curator has a recipe that does this. Please see TreeCache: http://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/tree-cache.html

Comment: I know this recipe. I want to know why my code does not work. I think I watch the child of "/aa", all changes about "/aa"'s children will trigger the watch. But it does not.

Comment: ZooKeeper has several types of watchers. In order to watch for data changes, you must first set a watch using `getData()`. Using ZooKeeper correctly is very difficult and is why Curator was created in the first place. I strongly recommend that you use one of Curator's pre-built recipes instead of trying to write ZooKeeper code directly.